# Как задать условие в функции Python при расчете интеграла?

Tags: python, циклы, while

Реализовал получение интеграла методом Симпсона. Его считает функция `integrated(x_0, x_n, n)`, где `x_0` - начало отрезка интегрирования, `x_n` - конец отрезка интегрирования, `n` - количество интервалов, на которые разбиваем отрезок интегрирования. Функция запрашивает  желаемую точность расчета `accuracy`.

Структурно функция `integrated()` содержит внутреннюю функцию `simpson(n)`, которая реализует алгоритм расчета. Затем считается погрешность `err_runge`, которая сравнивается с `accuracy`.

Если погрешность `err_runge` выше точности `accuracy`, количество разбиений `n` удваивается, и расчет начинается снова.

После расчета `simpson()` я реализовал цикл *while*, однако получил бесконечный цикл. Что исправить? Код:

```
def integrated(x_0, x_n, n):

    # 1. запросим точность 
    accuracy = float( input('Введите точность расчета (десятичная дробь): ') )
    
    # 2. Определим условие о том, что n должно быть четным 
    # (это является условием для вычисления погрешности по Рунге)
    assert n%2 == 0, 'Значение n должно быть четным'
    
    # 3. рассчитаем интеграл
    def simpson(n):
        ...
    
    # 4. Создадим для удобства переменные
    integ_1 = simpson(n)
    n *= 2
    integ_2 = simpson(n)

    # 5. применим критерий точности вычисления 
    err_simpson = abs((integ_2 - integ_1)/integ_2)
 
    # 6. Применим цикл
    while err_simpson > accuracy:
        integ_1 = integ_2
        n *= 2
        integ_2 = simpson(n)
   
    print('Интеграл по методу Симпсона: ', integ)
    print('Достигнутая ошибка интегрирования: ', err_simpson)
    
    return integ, err_runge, err_simpson
```

Comment: Добавьте ещё одну строчку  `err_simpson = abs((integ_2 - integ_1)/integ_2)` в конец цикла

Comment: @MBo, благодарю - добавил, работает. Кроме того, дополнительно добавил счетчик числа разбиений `max_iter = 100 # максимальное количество итераций для избежания бесконечного цикла`, который также считается в цикле и при переполнении счетчика останавливает расчет